# Why does light travel in forward direction?

Tags: visible-light, photons

Light from a point source follows the inverse square law and thus behaves like an expanding sphere. How is this phenomenon explained ?
Why doesn't it just *remains* where it started ? 
Why move at all ?

Comment: Contract backwards to what? It's already a point source in your question.

Comment: So basically you are saying there are no other option so it expands ? 
+Not expanding and not contracting is also an option.

Comment: What? It is a bunch of particles moving outwards, why would it contract or do something else?

Comment: @HritikNarayan  Why are they moving forwards only ? What gives them direction ?

Comment: Because they have a velocity? That is how things move.

Comment: Is there a reason you're asking this specifically about light, as opposed to, say, cannonballs?

Comment: Because of conservation of momentum, it cannot just stop and move backwards without any external influence

Comment: @WillO Cannon balls experience a force when they move in a particular direction. Light doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

Light from a point source travels outward in all directions from the source. It doesn't start far away and travel toward the source because the source is where energy is being converted from some other form to light.

If there were light travelling from some other place towards the source, that would mean that something was converting energy to light at that other place. In other words it would mean there was another source at the other place.

Comment: `Light from a point source travels outward in all directions from the source.` Why _travel_ at all ?